# QList and MyClass undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have weird problem with Qt 4.
I'm trying to make QList of MyClass, but it says MyClass: undeclared identifier.
I'm using it in global objects.. here's code and let me know what I'm doing wrong.
Regards.

global_objects.h:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_OBJECTS_H
#define GLOBAL_OBJECTS_H

#include <QList>
#include "myclass.h"

extern QList<MyClass*> Test; //undeclared identifier, why???

#endif // GLOBAL_OBJECTS_H
```

global_objects.cpp:

```
#include "global_objects.h"
QList <MyClass*> Test;
```

MyClass is empty QObject, haven't added anything yet. What's the problem ?!

Comment: is MyClass defined in the global namespace?

Comment: also, does myclass.h by any chance #include file global_objects.h (mutual #include)?

Comment: Nope, it's defined like this: class MyClass : public QObject and then Q_OBJECT macro

Comment: Yes, it does. myclass.h also includes global_objects.h

Comment: That is your problem then, you need to avoid mutual header inclusion. I am typing from a phone so formatting code is kind of challenging, but i will try to add code to my answer. anyway, just use a forward declaration of MyClass in global_objects.h instead of including myclass.h

Comment: I understand, but I have to work with it with bunch of classes, I need global variables too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mutual inclusion problem: for your purposes, i think it is sufficient to forward-declare MyClass in global_objects.h. You do not need to #include myclass.h there

Comment: I tried that, but still same problem. MyClass.h does not include global_objects.h, only global_objects.h include MyClass.h but same error :(

Comment: does myclass.h includes any other header which directly or indirectly includes global_object.h?

Comment: By the way, it's not mutual include problem, because I have #ifdef. Let me pastebin my code and will show you.

Comment: i don't think #ifdef saves you from mutual inclusion problems. if i were you i would first look for indirect mutual inclusion cycles and break them down through forward declarations. this is always possible

Comment: here: http://pastebin.com/tbG3Wmm2

P.S When I try QList with QString, QTcpSocket or any other thing, it works without any problems. It just hates my class.

Comment: Anyways, re-created MyClass.h and MyClass.cpp and not it works. Maybe it's some kind of bug?
Regards.

Comment: i am a bit out of ideas. i don't know Qt so i'm wondering if the Qt macros are ok, but i suppose they are. btw do you have a myclass.cpp file? does it compile there?

Comment: Ok. I strongly believe your problem was mutual inclusion. In the future, try to avoid it. Just an advice. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Did you include the `MyClass.h` into your `global_objects.cpp`?

I wonder if your use `MyClass` in `global_objects.cpp` then you should declare it with pre-complile command.

wish to help.

Comment: he did indirectly by including global_objects.h. the problem is that global_objects.h and myclass.h mutually include each other

Comment: I haven't included MyClass.h in global_objects.cpp, I tried it but still got same problem.

Comment: @OverFlowz: you did indirectly. global_objects.cpp includes global_objects.h and global_objects.h includes myclass.h, so by transitivity global_object.cpp includes myclass.h